# how to add field to userchangeform?

Tags: django

I have extended the **abstract user class** but the fields I added is **phone number** but this field did not appear in **user change form** how would I add this field to **user  change form** ?

Comment: Can you show us your code? And tell us which libraries you are using (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

After adding the phone number field to your model and registration form, you can add it to the UserUpdateForm as follows.

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm', 'phone']

    username = forms.CharField(label = 'Username')
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm = forms.CharField(label = 'Confirm Password', widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    phone = forms.CharField() #or if django have a phone field set phonefield

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        
        

        if password and confirm and password != confirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords doesn't match")
        if email == False:
            raise forms.ValidationError("A valid Email Address")

        values = {
        'username' : username,
        'password' : password,
        'email' : email,
        'phone' : phone,
        }

        return values
```